# Python with NetMiko. Is there a way to specify source interface (socket) on the server?

Tags: python, ssh, netmiko

Trying to figure out how to use socket source with netmiko. So far no luck...(

```
 from netmiko import ConnectHandler
 import socket

 cisco_881 =
 {
'device_type': 'cisco_ios',

'host':   '192.168.2.241',
'username': 'admin',
'password': 'admin', 
'secret': 'admin', 
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_881)
output = net_connect.send_command('show interface')
print(output)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  `netmiko` makes an ssh connection to the device and communicates over that.

Comment: Specify on the with ConnectHandler the source adapter interface for out going netmiko connections.

Answer (score 2):

***This works for SSH***

```
import socket
sok = socket.socket()
sok.bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))
sok.connect((host, 22))
#Then on the ConnectHandler specify the src socket.
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_881, sock=sok).
```

**For Telnet**, Netmiko use the telnetlib and it only accepts host, port, timeout arguments. Only solution was to copy the telnetlib.py to current directory and modify the line below. If anyone finds an alternate method please post!!!

***This works for telnet***

```
#Modify telnetlib.py

#From:
self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout

#To: 
self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout, ("Your source IP", 0))
```

Thank you.